# How do I use 2 controllers to play local multiplayer via remote play?

Tags: xbox-series-x-series-s

Recently, I have been testing out the new remote play feature on my phone, so I can play anywhere I want.

I connected my two Xbox controllers to my phone via Bluetooth, and they are shown as separate connections. However, when I play Mortal Kombat 11 both controllers control the same player, where when playing directly through the Xbox console, each controller controls their own respective player.

How do I use 2 controllers to play local multiplayer via remote play?

Comment: I was able to answer your question. Sorry it wasn't the answer you were looking for - I hope they change it, in the future. For now, I have suggested an edit to change the scope of your question; I understand your asking so you can play a specific game, but your question is actually about a feature with the console, not a feature with the game itself. By broadening the scope to ask 'how do I do this with this feature' instead of 'how do I do this with this feature in this game', your question becomes more useful to other users.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, the answer is simply that you can't. Xbox Play Anywhere is designed to allow a single person to play directly from their phone, and does not support additional players, even when the game normally would when playing it directly from the console. This has been confirmed by Microsoft, themselves.

> **Can a friend connect their controller to my mobile device to play local co-op with me?**
>
> No, remote play supports only one connection at a time.
> ***[- Remote Play Frequantly Asked Questions @ support.xbox.com](https://support.xbox.com/en-AU/help/games-apps/troubleshooting/troubleshoot-remote-play-gaming)***

Comment: Would it be possible to connect two mobile devices to a single console, then connect one controller one each? (Just asking, never had an Xbox)

Comment: @Zoma, I have my suspicions. There is no official evidence, so it would need to be something I'd test from home.